# Does TransactionScope works for different Context object

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am using `TransactionScope` in BLL. I have repository classes on Data access layer which creates own `Context` per crud. Will this work?

In Bll:

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required)) 
    { 
        rep.addItme(Myentity);
        rep.updateItme(MyAnotherEntity);
            scope.Complete(); 
    }
```

In DataAccess:

```
class rep
{
  void addItmem(Entity entity)
  {
    using(var context=new MydbContext)
     {  
     //---state is set here
     context.Entity.add(entity);
     context.SaveChanges();
    }

   }
  void updateItem(Entity entity)
 {
 using(var context=new MydbContext)
   {
     //--state is set here
     context.Entity.add(entity);
      context.SaveChanges();
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes. The best way is to test it. Try to throw an exception in `updateItem` and see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All DbContext that is instantiated inside the scope (brackets) of a TransactionScope will automatically be enrolled in the TransactionScope's inner transaction, by default it's the the Ambient transaction. So yes it should work.

Comment: I am not so sure, because each dbcontext will probably have its own connection, that means separate transactions. Even if it works in some setups (due to connection pool or for some other reason) it is doubtfully guaranteed to do so, while [Database.BeginTransaction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456843.aspx) in EF6 or using a single DbContext for early versions is a sure way.